# Update column with array entry; create column if it does not exist

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

```
                            r.table("bets").filter({id: betID}).update({
                                votes: r.row('votes').append({
                                    userID: userID,
                                    vote: vote
                                })
                            }).run(connection, function(err, result) {
                                // ...
                            });
```

My goal ist to update a document in the `bets` table with the given `betID`. I want to update the column `votes`, which might not exist. If it does not exist, I want to create the column, and append the array element afterwards. If it exists, I just want to append the array element.
`result.replaced` returns 1, which is correct, but the column `votes` is not created... any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
                            var newVote = {
                                userID: userID,
                                vote: vote
                            };

                            r.table("bets").filter({id: betID}).update({
                                votes: r.row('votes').default([]).append(newVote)
                            }).run(connection, function(err, result) {

                            });
```

See. https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/update/